# How to make a NSStackView/UIStackView function like a float:left in css

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, interface-builder

I'm trying to make a breadcrumb navigation section in my macOS App, but I'm limited in width space because of other views that appear on the right. So I want to somehow wrap the items to the next line if I run out of room on the first line.

So this is the basic setup I'm trying.

1. The StackView is in horizontal orientation.
2. The StackView width is fixed.
3. Text fields get added to the stackview via addArragnedSubView() but their frame widths are **variable**, meaning not equal.

I've been playing with all the fill options and it seems like StackViews try to stretch and contract the views no matter what option you choose (by design most likely). Is it fair to say StackViews aren't meant for variable widths and view wrapping?

The concept is very similar to the float:left css attribute in Web that allows elements to continue to be "stuffed" to the left of a div for example. If that element can't "fit" on that row, it gets added on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to to. Would a UICollectionView be a better fit for that? Maybe you could try something like:

https://github.com/riteshhgupta/TagCellLayout

Sounds like you are asking for something with more of a grid layout rather than what a UIStackView provides.